# How to wrap in transaction BLL methods when using n-tier with EF on a separate project

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, n-tier-architecture

I have this setup: Presentation -> Service -> Business Logic -> DAL. The Business Logic uses the DAL when something needs to be retrieved/persisted to the DB. Right now, I have this method in BLL:

```
public class BLL
{
    public void CreateItem(Item item)
    {

        // START I want this in transaction

        AddItemModel(item.Model);
        _DAL.AddItem(item);

        // END I want this in transaction

    }

    public void AddModel(ItemModel model)
    {
        _DAL.AddItemModel(model)
    }
}
```

In the code, when I add an item, I need to first Add its model before adding the item. I want this to either all commit or all fail but I'm not sure what's the best (or appropriate) way to do this based on my situation. I have DbContext in a separate project, and the context is not referenced by BLL (but is referenced by DAL).

Questions and concerns right now are:

a. Should I do the transaction in DAL (I think I shouldn't; not sure though) using DbContext as UoW.

b. Some say use UoW pattern. I understand its purpose but I don't know exactly where to put it. Should it be in BLL or DAL or Service layer?

c. Should context not be in BLL or is it OK to use it there?

I'm just really confused. I know there's a lot I can do to make this work but I am not sure what is the correct or clean way of doing this in this situation.

Comment: Your repository could be at home in the BLL, some don't even split the DAL and BLL, because you have, another layer of complexity is introduced. If you have the DAL performing all data access operations why would you put the context in the DAL? The BLL in the sense you are using it (with a seperate DAL) should be platform independent, so it seems logical that the context should not go in your BLL.

Comment: @Paul Zahra: "If you have the DAL performing all data access operations why would you put the context in the DAL?" The last DAL here, did you mean BLL?

Comment: Yes soz... wife rang me on phone lol... should read... why would you put the context in the BLL?

Comment: "Perfection exists as an abstraction of our minds, but is not attainable in the physical world."... just do a good job is all that can be reasonably asked... an excellent solution for one problem is a poor solution for a similar problem.

Comment: I would consider the market for the application; enterprise? = seperate concerns as much as you have done... small to medium business? = consider not having the overhead of a business layer at all and do it all in the DAL (i.e. the DAL and BLL become one)